# error: Unable to resolve build file: XCBCore.BuildFile (namedReferencesCannotBeResolved) (in target 'CentralCasting')

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode10.2

I am facing an issue while running iOS code from react-native

Unable to resolve build file: XCBCore.BuildFile (namedReferencesCannotBeResolved) (in target 'myProjectName')

I have tried many solution from stackover flow but nothing working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed the plugin's and again add it. And do the Manual linking the plugin's in Code don't go for Pod's install.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to the menu Xcode -> Preferences and select the locations tab
2. Click the little arrow next to 'Derived Data' to open it in Finder
3. Quit xcode
   4.You will see a bunch of folder in the DerivedData, delete all of them.
4. Restart Xcode and build your project.

Following above steps resolved the issue for me. (Xcode 11.3.1)